# Trying to connect sql database in xampp

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root'
$password = '';
$db ='members';

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die("Unable to connect to the server!");

mysqli_select_db("members", $connection) or die("Couldn't connect to the database!");
```

I have installed xampp and create database named "members". I tried to connect it to phpmyadmin but didn't work. I try to google all the answers since three days but in vain. Please help me...

Comment: your given code not having line number 11. Show full code, and remove the image. Just paste your error here. Also stop using deprecated library`mysql_*`. Start using `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: I have edit it correctly and replace mysqli but the errors is still there.Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$password' (T_VARIABLE) in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\codeinventor\connection.php on line 5. My head is spinning and confusing

Comment: here is https://jsfiddle.net/pb2on5qp/ check it

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$password' (T_VARIABLE) in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\codeinventor\connection.php on line 5 this is an error nothing is working

Comment: i get error of Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$password' (T_VARIABLE) in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\codeinventor\connection.php on line 5

Comment: ill try again and let you know

Comment: Im trying to mark your right answer inside the chat but couldn't find where to tick?

Comment: relax. Ok at least say that.. Don't get frustrated.

Comment: Now i got it there you go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$db ='members';

$connection = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);// you can select db separately as you did already
if($connection){
     // do all your stuff that you want
}else{
   echo "db connection error because of".mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are your credentials for username and password correct?

By default, the localhost has username = root and password as blank.

Also, what's the issue? Is it showing "Unable to connect to the server!"?

Comment: Im new to sql. Yes it is unable to connect to the server. I tried username and password several times but not connecting. Even I create new account for username and password but still it is not connect.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon after `$user = 'root'` and you are using a mixture of `mysql_` and `mysqli_`. Also, you could select a table by passing a fourth argument to `mysqli_connect()`

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$db ='members';

$connection = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);// you can select db separately as you did already
if($connection){ echo "Connected Successfully";}else{ echo "Error connecting: . mysqli_connect_error()"; }
```

Use `mysqli_` to do queries:

```
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO user_login (uname,upassword,email) VALUES ('$uname','$upassword','$email')");
```

I recommend you to use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

So the above query would look like:

```
$stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO user_login (uname,upassword,email) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $uname, $upassword, $email);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: At-least change the comment `// you can select db separately as you did already`. Seems like copy and paste. Bad habbit

Comment: Lol, I was too lazy to type :D.

Comment: i did as you said. It didn't work. Look Im going mad now lol... I don't know what to do i think somewhere went wrong...  as i have to submitted my project to university...

Comment: try your username & password to login in using phpMyAdmin

Comment: well let me explain to you I have create html in everything to be ready. Then i convert index.html into php and already installed xampp. I click start in apache and sql. I have create database and table in phpmyadmin. Now I have code in connection.php. But it didnt connect to database I don't know what is wrong with that? It didn't add to database after fill the form.

Comment: I didn't find username and password to login in phpmyadmin. please tell me in procedure

Comment: @AlziraBarretto try `root` or `password`  as password

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106128/discussion-between-user3284463-and-alzira-barretto).